# Calling a method when another activity finishes

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, activity-finish

I am using a library that presents an Activity on top of another Activity.  I am not working with Bundles or onCreate().

So...Activity A is running in the background and Activity B is running in the foreground.  I want to call a method in Activity A when Activity B is finished.

Any ideas/suggestions on how I can accomplish this?  This is perhaps an algorithmic question.  I am still a novice programmer, so I really appreciate the help!  Thanks!

Comment: I think you should improve what you are asking, be more specific, besides I don't understand what use can have an Activity without overriding onCreate() method.

Comment: which part is not clear?

Comment: I'm not clear on how you presents an Activity on top of another Activity. Whats the difference of this as compared to normal activity stack?

Comment: the difference is i am not using Bundles or onCreate()

Comment: can you please share your code ? for more clarification

Answer (score 1):

I think the most close to what you want is using `startActivityForResult`, like this:

```
   ...
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.some.foo");
   startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST);
   ...
```

And call the method you want(when activity foo finishes) from:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int arg1, int arg2, Intent data )
{
   if(arg1 == REQUEST)
   {
       MethodToCall();
   }
}
```

Comment: i am not familiar with startActivityForResult. ill have to take a look at it. thanks

Comment: unfortunately that will not work for me. with the library i am using, i do not have intents.

Answer (score 1):

You can reformat your activities to Fragments and do anything you want - you will have direct access to methods of fragment A from fragment B.